# Pi use monitor and projector at the same time

Tags: usb, pi-4, pi-3b+, hdmi

I have Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. Now I use Pi with monitor using HDMI port but my project requere to have connected projector and to show static images on it. Projector will be controled with script(Python, if it is neccesery C) commands - start, show this image, show this image, ...., stop.

Is there any way to do this?

My projector: https://www.emag.bg/proektor-excelvan-t260-domashno-kino-hdmi-320x240-native-701030/pd/DD7TGNMBM/?ref_id=667313116
My screen: https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/model/UM.QS0EE.A01

Some ideas:

- Connecting projector with USB or another way.
- Connecting monitor by
  some another way and projector with HDMI.
- Buy Raspberry pi 4

Comment: Buy a Raspberry Pi4 which has 2 hdmi outputs.

Comment: Option "New Pi" is my last option because it is investment - new pi, power cable, fan, 2x mini hdmi. Also I don't know why but almost everywhere Pi4 is out of stock. More precisely Pi4 8GB because if i gave money I want to know it will work for a lot of projects.